# El Capitan Mission Control: How to select an app with the keyboard?

Tags: mac, macos

I've looked high and low but can't find a keyboard shortcut to select an app from Mission Control.

I want to press F3, then "some keyboard key(s) and not have to click on the trackpad" to select the app I want.

Comment: Seems there's no way to do this. Hopefully Apple will add this feature in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The best alternative solution:

Press command-space to open spotlight, then start typing the title of the app (or whatever) you want and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

There is free app called [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en) that allows you to completely customize your keyboard short cuts on OS X including assigning "Launcher" keys combinations to launch apps.

Full disclaimer:  I have used Karabiner, but I prefer to just use Spotlight (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd>) to find the app I am looking for; much less to remember.

Comment: I'm using BTT (BetterTouchTool) to add gesture features to the trackpad and it also allows for custom keyboard short cut assignment. If you haven't checked out BTT, give it a whirl. It has a 45 day trail and I have a feeling I'll be fully dependent on it by then ... ;-)